# Asymmetric Crypto on Android

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I would like to ask if i can use Asymmetric Crypto (like RSA or ECC) on android mobile phones, how, and what are the best libraries i should use.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is Java, you can use the Bouncy Castle Cryptographic Library :)

http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

You can use RSA or ElGamal for Asymmetric Cryptography :)

http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html