# Encrypt data that is sending from mobile App, is this possible?

Tags: android, ios, email, sendmail, encryption

I'm making a IOS and a Android App with the option to send a Mail to my company for contact or whatever, now i was looking for a way to make that email encrypted, is this possible or will i found a dead end?

I've searched google, blogs, stackoverflow etc, the only thing what i found where different Apps that send email encrypted but that is not the way i'm looking for i think, the mail is sending from my App, not from another App..

Many thanks!

Comment: Encrypt (just as anything would be encrypted). Put in email. Send. - Which part is the issue? I would recommend [asymmetric (public-key) encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) so people can't steal the key in the application and use it for decryption (this won't prevent spoofing, but it will prevent sniffing).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127267/asymmetric-crypto-on-android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069369/rsa-encryption-difference-between-java-and-android

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the data using an external library. Then you can put the data in an email and send it.

Here's a good encryption technique using AES 128 cypher:

http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings

**Update:**

Referring the comment from pst, I agree that asymmetric key encryption is better in this case.

For asymmetric key encryption, you can use [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) like so:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
```

It has different modes and schemes you can use it with. So you might want to read up on these:

http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html#pkcs1schemes
http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2009/01/08/cryptographic-padding-in-rsa/

Also see the Cipher class in andorid:
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

Comment: AES is likely a poor choice here because it is symmetric. If someone gets access to the key in the application they can decrypt the email data.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot via API say that mail should apply some encryption automagically. you have to do this and then put that into the mail