# How do I authenticate an internal API for an iPhone app?

Tags: security

We have a simple API that we dont want the external world using, and only want our iPhone clients to use.

How can I authenticate the client for the API for a mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an API that your client can access, you won't be able to prevent a determined skilled person from also using your API (as the user can identify any secrets stored in the client).

If you just want to prevent casual use then a relatively simple way to authenticate a client would be to have a shared static secret that is stored in the client and use that with for example an [HMAC based API authentication scheme](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/HMACAuth.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the question which is internally similar to what you are asking:

[Provide secure Facebook authentication with my Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456829/provide-secure-facebook-authentication-with-my-server/14507550#14507550)

Here is what I replied over there:

It's called remote attestation. There are A LOT of problems with this.

Before you go into this direction, you need to ask yourself two questions

- Who are you protecting against?
- How much am I willing to invest?

If you are protecting yourself against a student with very limited knowledge, who may write another mobile app which will use your sever then you are fine with some shared secret.

If you are protecting against just a little bit more sophisticated software engineer (who can reverse engineer your application) - it won't be enough. This engineer can extract a secert from your app and use it in his application.

You can read about remote attestation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computing#Remote_attestation) and [here](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~guttman/pubs/good_attest.pdf).

Solutions which can protect you from simple reverse engineering are quite complex.